# Pact-broker : Cannot able to see pact broker screen in http://localhost:8080/

Tags: pact, pact-broker

I'm new to pact. followed the instructions [https://github.com/DiUS/pact_broker-docker/blob/master/POSTGRESQL.md](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ6N5.png) to set up the pact-broker in dockerized environment.
The containers Up and running.[image]

In browser, I can see postgres listening at http://localhost:8080/

[image]

But I cannot able to see the following pact-broker screen to publish/verify the contract file. someone please help. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The link you've provided is also incorrect (it's pointing to the image). Port 8080  isn't mentioned on that page, so I'm not sure where you got that from.

Answer (score 1):

From the images you shared, looks like the port is `80` not `8080`

Try at `localhost:80`.